Inaccessible cardinals and consistency of ZFC
I don't see how to state and prove rigorously the following result. Which of the following statement makes sense and is true ?
For all $\phi$ in $ZFC$, we have :
$ZFC+\exists \kappa'(\kappa' \text{ inaccessible})\vdash \forall\kappa(\kappa \text{ inaccessible}\rightarrow \phi^{V_{\kappa}})$
For all $\phi$ in ZFC and for all inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, we have :
$ZFC+\exists \kappa'(\kappa' \text{ inaccessible})\vdash \phi^{V_{\kappa}}$
For $\kappa$ an inaccessible cardinal, $V_{\kappa}\models ZFC$


For all $\phi$ in $ZFC$, we have :
$ZFC+\exists \kappa'(\kappa' inaccessible)\vdash \forall\kappa(\kappa inaccessible\rightarrow \phi^{V_{\kappa}})$

This makes sense and is true, provided we interpret $\phi^{V_\kappa}$ to be the statement internal to set theory that the code of the formula $\phi$ is true in $V_\kappa.$ And you don't need the extra assumption that there exists an inaccessible cardinal... it would hold just fine (vacuously) if there were none.
EDIT: As Lorenzo notes in the comments, there's not actually an issue with interpreting the notation $\phi^{V_\kappa}$ as just the relativization of $\phi$... not sure what I was thinking.

For all $\phi$ in ZFC and for all inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, we have :
$ZFC+\exists \kappa'(\kappa' inaccessible)\vdash \phi^{V_{\kappa}}$

This one does not make sense, since it doesn't make sense to talk about provability in ZFC (+inaccessibles) of a formula with parameters, which $\phi^{V_\kappa}$ is.

For $\kappa$ an inaccessible cardinal, $V_{\kappa}\models ZFC$

This makes sense as a statement of set theory and is provable in ZFC. Your first statement is almost the statement that this last one is provable in ZFC (+inaccessibles, but as I mentioned, that's irrelevant). Only the difference is there you quantified over formulas in the metatheory, whereas $V_\kappa\models ZFC$ means we're quantifying over formulas internally in the set theory . i.e., using similar notation as your first, we have $$ ZFC\vdash \forall\kappa \mbox{ inaccessible},\forall \phi\in ZFC,\;\phi^{V_\kappa}$$

It can be useful to abuse notation less to keep things straight. If I were being careful, I'd write your first statement

For every $\phi$ in ZFC, we have $$ ZFC\vdash \forall \kappa\mbox{ inaccesible,}\; V_\kappa\models \ulcorner \phi\urcorner$$

although (see edit above) the original phrasing does work as is when we take $\phi^{V_\kappa}$ as an abbreviation of the relativization of $\phi$ (which is itself a first order formula in $\kappa$).
and your third

$$ ZFC\vdash \forall\kappa \mbox{ inaccessible},\forall \phi\in \ulcorner ZFC\urcorner,\;\phi^{V_\kappa}$$

using Quine corners to denote when there's some coding of formulas from the metatheory involved.

We don't need codes for formulae  to make sense of the first statement. The sentence $\phi^{V_\kappa}$ is the the relativization of the formula $\phi$ to $V_\kappa$ (which is a $\Delta_1^{\mathsf{ZF}}$-definable set with parameter $\kappa$). Codes of formulae are needed only to make formal sense of the third statement.

@Lorenzo What do you mean by $V_{\kappa}$ is a $\Delta_1^{ZF}$-definable set with parameter $\kappa$ ? Could you write explicitly a formula characterizing the set $V_{\kappa}$ with a parameter $\kappa$ ?

@spaceisdarkgreen Could you prove it ?

For the third statement, is it enough to simply show $V_{\kappa}\models \phi$ as if we were in basic logic,model theory ? I mean just by making a basic metatheoric proof of the fact that $V_{\kappa}$ satisfies each axiom of $ZFC$ ?

@Lorenzo yes, you’re right.

@MamounAich Prove what?

So $\aleph_0$ is an accessible cardinal?

@user14111 Yes... $\aleph_0$ is not inaccessible. (It's regular and strong limit, but inaccessibles have to additionally be uncountable, if that's the confusion?)

@spaceisdarkgreen Prove the third statement. Is it enough to simply show Vκ⊨ϕ
as if we were in basic logic,model theory ? I mean just by making a basic metatheoric proof of the fact that Vκ satisfies each axiom of ZFC ?

@MamounAich Yes. Basic logic and model theory can be carried out formally in ZFC, so there's nothing more to it.

And I suppose you would also say that $\aleph_0$ is not measurable and not compact. Just pointing out how unnatural it is to artificially exclude $\aleph_0$ which is the prototype for those properties and the one example that is known to exist. I guess the motivation is that "uncountable inaccessible cardinal" is too much of a mouthful.

@user14111 Yes the reason that it's standard to exclude $\aleph_0$ in the definition of large cardinal properties that might otherwise hold of it is because in practice it needs to be excluded more often than not (e.g. in this theorem under discussion) we don't want to qualify with "uncountable" all the time.

@spaceisdarkgreen So we don't have to use the completeness theorem and to show that $N\models \forall \kappa$ inaccessible, $\phi^{V_{\kappa}}$ for all model $N$ of $ZFC$ ? We suppose a "real" inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ and we show as we said that $V_{\kappa}\models \phi$, for each $\phi$ in $ZFC$.

@MamounAich Yes, working in ZFC, you assume there's an inacessible $\kappa$, and then show that $V_\kappa\models \phi$ for each ZFC axiom $\phi.$

There must be times when you want to include $\aleph_0$ and then it must be a bit annoying to have to say "let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal or $\aleph_0$." Hmm. We often want to consider primes $p\ne2$ but instead of excluding $2$ from the definition of a prime we speak of "odd primes". Too bad there isn't a one-syllable word for "uncountable". Well, there's the word "large". We could speak of "measurable cardinals" ($\aleph_0$ included) and "large measurable cardinals" ($\aleph_0$ excluded). That would have worked. Too late now, I guess.

@user14111 Yes, "more often than not" just means what it says. Surely an example exists where it would be convenient to include $\aleph_0$, but I can't immediately think of one. Whereas I can think of quite a few interesting consequences of measurability that don't hold for $\aleph_0$ off the top of my head.
